# RPM skipping files on install

Tags: linux, rpm, file-copy

I am installing an rpm package and it appears to be skipping certain files without giving me any notice as to what the issue is.

When I execute

```
rpm -ivh package_name.rpm
```

the rpm provides me with no indication that the installation failed.

After executing this, I verify the installation:

```
rpm -V package_name
```

And I see that some files are reported as missing
missing    `/path/to/some/crucial/file`

When I look into my / directory, I see that a few files were created which start with `u2dtmp*`. These are the files which do not get created.

I have attempted to remove old locks from my rpm installation and cleaned the database `rpm --rebuilddb`, but nothing seems to allow these files to be installed successfully.

This issue only appears on a single machine. It installs successfully on other linux machines which have the same os.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some work a solution was found. Inside the rpm, a few dos2unix calls were made. A coworker of mine was able to determine that the verson of dos2unix that was installed had some issues.

After upgrading to the latest version, the u2dtmp* files disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

For some unfathomable reason, `rpm -V package` complains on many freshly installe packages. Also, use `rpm -U...`, that will not just try to install the package but also delete old versions.

Why aren't you using yum? It is a frontend to rpm, automating many tasks. The yum-utils package contains package-cleanup, which helps getting rid of duplicates, leftovers from failed installations, and similar cruft.

Comment: attempting the rpm upgrade [-U] didn't seem to resolve my issue. The reason I don't use yum is because it isn't installed, and I am lazy. [I know that it is a bad excuse, but oh well]. This seems like it is a genuine issue with rpm, mainly caused by an issue with my machine.

Comment: Install yum then?

Comment: Oh, and exactly what packages are you trying to install, and what does the rpm -Uhv command say?

Comment: The packages are internal applications. The upgrade command doesnt really report anything of interest. [the only things which show are from scripts which i cant really show]